# Oracle. Пересекающиеся столбцы в двух таблицах

Tags: sql, oracle

Доброго времени суток!

Есть две таблицы с большим количеством столбцов, больше 200.
Нужно определить одинаковые столбцы у данных таблиц, и вывести их в результат, можно построчно, не важно как. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.column_name from USER_TAB_COLUMNS t1, USER_TAB_COLUMNS t2
 where t1.table_name = '&1' 
   and t2.table_name = '&2'
   and T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME
```

Спросит название первой таблицы и второй, выведет пересекающиеся колонки.